# I messed up an answer - twice. What's the right way to proceed?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I tried a couple of times to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264224/how-do-i-filter-a-wmi-search-on-what-i-think-is-a-nested-property/44264847#44264847). I got quick on the draw and saw an error in the code, which I "fixed" in my first answer, but when I got called out, I whacked the answer and tried again.

Through a series of backs-and-forths, I arrived at what I believe will prove to be the right answer....but along the way, I ended up replacing the entire (second) answer text. This, of course, invalidates the comments underneath...and so I'm torn.

I feel like I did it wrong twice...and probably should have continually edited the first answer...but now it's (from my point of view) all gakked up. The first answer is now completely out of context, and the second answer has effectively trashed its chain of commentary. How do I best proceed?

Comment: Flag a moderator and ask him to clean up the comments since they are now all obsolete.

Comment: What Hans said. Make sure to give a good reason to the mod, "comments are obsolete" is NOT one, "comments are obsolete since I fixed all the points raised in them (see edit history)" is MUCH better. Don't assume that the mod has *any* knowledge of the language/tech in your answer (because often they won't).

Comment: Note that you can also simply flag a comment as obsolete when you see this happen on other posts. Comments aren't meant to preserve information in the long term anyway. As Alexei said, comments are to clarify the post so it's *expected* that they'll become obsolete.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Flag comments obsolete, make sure post stand by itself.

It is fine to edit (or completely rewrite) the answer more than once if you found (yourself or via comments) if original approach is wrong in some way. You can hint on original approach with "... does not work because ..." remarks, but it is not required.

Comments are to clarify the post - since you've made an edit that clarifies (either by removing or fixing) all concerns you are free to mark all related comments "obsolete" and be done.

If you want to you can ping whoever commented on the post with "answer updated" (also most comments so far look like "you have syntax error" - I would not ping for those).

Side note: avoid historical notes/editing remarks in the post like "previous deleted version", "Rewrite of Answer", "EDIT:", "Update:" as such text unlikely to provide more information for the answer.

Comment: Yes - I've removed the "historical" notes to the modified question. I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: The rewards system makes people over anxious and sometimes even uptight.